# Reverse accidental tag of release branch in Team Foundation

Tags: tfs, version-control

I have just realised that I did not label all files in "Main" in a Team Foundation repository with a release label and then create a branch from that label in order to build a release, as shown below.

[image: Intended label and branch sequence]

Instead, I created a release branch from "Main" and then labelled the files in that release branch.

[image: Actual branch and label sequence]

The consequence of this is that I cannot recreate the state of the release by branching from "Main" using the release label as it's on the wrong branch.

How do I fix this?

Is there any way I can correct this by labelling the appropriate versions of the files on the Main branch so that I could, in principle, branch from the appropriate label on "Main"?

Comment: In TFS, labels let you take a snapshot of your files so that at a later date you can refer back to that snapshot.  Why you need to create labels for both Main branch and Release ? Did the "main" means the label name, or just main branch? And what's your ultimately goal? Could you explain more clearly?

Comment: Hopefully my intent is clearer now.  I appreciate that visualising this can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the wrong label, delete that one. You could just [create a new Release-1.1 label](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-labels-take-snapshot-your-files#apply-a-label)  on "main" with specific **changeset** in the **Version** list.

Note you are **labeling by changeset not labeling a changeset**. This means that if you right click the containing folder and view labels it will look like it put the label on the first changeset of the branch (as the main folder likely hasn't changed since the first changeset).

If you right click in source control explorer and select -> find -> find by label, then select your label and click edit, you'll see a list of **all files** in the label and the changeset of when they **last changed prior to** the label changeset.

TFS Labels is marking a point in time, just like back to the time you created the release branch from "main", and let you take a snapshot of all your files on "main".

After this, you could branch from the appropriate ***new*** Release-1.1 label on "Main"

Comment: My Release-1.1 branch has multiple change sets in it.  So the label applies across a group of change sets as you suggest.

Does this imply that the smoothest way to achieve what I want is to find the time stamp associated with the original label on the release branch and create a new label on the main branch associated with the same time stamp?  

N.B. That does appear to give me what I want, but that does not mean it is correct!